# Bibliography in reverse order of entrance in .bib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

When I type:

```
@ARTICLE{article1,
  author  = {AAA}, 
  title = {New Method1},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article2,
  author  = {BBB}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}
```

the desirable order is

> [1] BBB,Article2,...
>
> [2] AAA, Article1,..

In other words, I want the opposite of what `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` give me. Anyone?

EDIT. I extend the question by addidng more information. I want to import files from publications.bib using multibib package.

```
 documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
 \moderncvstyle{classic}                            
 \moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{article}{{Articles}}

.
.
.

\section{Publications}

\nocitearticle{article1, article2}
\bibliographystylearticle{unsrt}
\bibliographyarticle{publications}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel But I dont want an alphabetical order. I tried that and it didnt work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I edited the question. Please see detailed explanation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Oh, sorry for rather trivial and silly question. I just need to change \nocitearticle{article1, article2} to \nocitearticle{article2, article1}. Thanks anyway for quick responce!
Edit. I can use your answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bibliography style `plain`. The compilation steps are shown by the rules of `arara`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article1,
  author  = {AAA}, 
  title = {New Method1},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article2,
  author  = {BBB}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{article2} and \cite{article1}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

With the result:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the `.bib` file doesn't have anything strange, that is it contains only `@article` or `@book` entries (all kinds of entries are supported, but not `@STRING` or `@COMMENT`), the following should do.

We read the `.bib` file building a list of the keys in reversed order, then issue the relevant `\nocite` command.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article1,
  author  = {AAA}, 
  title = {New Method1},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article2,
  author  = {BBB}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article3,
  author  = {CCC}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article4,
  author  = {DDD}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}

@ARTICLE{article5,
  author  = {EEE}, 
  title = {New Method2},
  year    ={2013},
  journal = {SuperJournal},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\readbib}{ m }
 {
  \makaroni_readbib:n { #1 }
 }
\clist_new:N \g_makaroni_keys_clist

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^^A }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \makaroni_readbib:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\@ }
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_lccode:nn { `\^^A } { `\@ }
  \tl_to_lowercase:n
   {
    \group_end:
    \cs_set_eq:NN ^^A \__makaroni_active_at:w
   }
  \input{#1.bib}
  \group_end:
  \exp_args:Nx \nocite { \g_makaroni_keys_clist }
 }
\group_end:

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__makaroni_active_at:w #1#
 {
  \__makaroni_process_entry:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__makaroni_process_entry:n #1
 {
  \__makaroni_add_key:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__makaroni_add_key:w #1 , #2 \q_stop
 {
  \clist_gput_left:Nn \g_makaroni_keys_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\readbib{\jobname}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the example self contained.

[image]

The method is similar to the one employed in `usebib.sty`. The `@` is made active and defined to read up to the first brace; then another macro is called that absorbs the entire entry and calls another one that isolates the key, adding it to the left of a comma list variable. Then, after ending the file to read, a `\nocite` command is issued with the (expanded) clist contents as its argument.